# Is there an alternative to apple's standard wireless bluetooth trackpad? I.e., an aftermarket version of the same basic thing?

Tags: bluetooth, magic-trackpad

I have had continuing problems with apple's bluetooth wireless trackpad. the first one had strange performance problems -- I got a friendly apple agent to exchange it for me.  The new one was better, but after a while its front rubber feet (which act as its press-to-click switch) stop clicking correctly...  I want to replace this!

SO, Can you identify another wireless trackpad that works just like apple's?   By logitech or some other third party company?  I haven't found one.

A bonus question: If you recommend wireless alternatives for apple's bluetooth keyboard, that would be handy too -- mine works OK but I'm not a huge fan, could use a better keyboard (since I know there are some serious keyboard nerds out there that know the various mechanical switches used, etc.)  For the record I have no problem with considering the "broken into two sections" ergo style keyboards...

Answer (score 1):

All I can find is the "Logitech Wireless Touchpad", but it seems to be for Windows only. Maybe you've just had bad luck with the trackpads? Or did you first one also have it's rubber feet wear down?

Comment: well, it's a long story. the first one had this strange deal where it would often interpret a regular touchpad touch-to-click as a RIGHT click. drove me nuts. and it also had this issue where the rubber button-feet would become uneven and therefore only one of them would wind up having pressure... like when one of a table's legs is shorter than the other three, so it hovers a bit... then, this new one was fine until it wound up perfectly replicating that second problem.  Perhaps I press hard on a trackpad so the entire body gets warped after a year.